# Unable to install vim plugin in raspberry pi

Tags: vimrc, plugin-python-mode

I am trying to install plugin for python in vim,but i am unable to do that. I removed vi tiny from Raspberry pi and installed vi 8.0 I followed instruction from this site

https://realpython.com/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/

I updated my vimrc file from sudo user in folder /home/etc/vim/vimrc

added these lines in vimrc file.

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle
" used Bundle instead of Plugin)

" ...

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

whenever I trying to install plugin I get an error E942: Not an editor command: PluginInstall

[image]

```
:Scriptname
```

show this

[image]

Comment: If you get `not an editor command` it means that Vundle is not properly installed or not properly added to Vim's runtime path and thus it doesn't know the `:PluginInstall` command. You could check that the git clone of Vundle created a directory in `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`, check that Vundle and your vimrc are shown in the result of  `:scriptname` and give us a feedback on that. (Also `set nocompatible` is not required: if you have a `.vimrc` file, then it sets `nocompatible` for you so you're better off without it, it has nothing to do with your problem but it's still good to know)

Comment: No vundle in :scriptname please help me

Comment: The path to your vimrc file looks strange.  Is your user called `etc`? Is `$HOME` the folder `/home/etc`?  Either way your vimrc file should be in `~/.vim/vimrc`. *Notice the dot!*

Comment: vimrc path in raspberry pi is `/home/etc/vim/vmrc`